# GLSL time for function in shader

Tags: opengl, optimization, time, lag

I would like to know if there is a way to calculate the time (or number of operations) that a function take in glsl program?
Being quite new to glsl and the way GPU works, it's hard and take me time to optimize a glsl shader; and my multipass rendering is very laggy.
So my goal would be to focus more on slower function.
Does a thing could help me?

I'm working on VS2015, and sadly, my GPU doesn't allow NSight to works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Shaders run paralelized in GPU. You can't find the number of operations per shader, because you really don't know how many "gpu-cores" are running and how the gpu-compiler optimized the shaders.

You can measure the time ellapsed for a draw command. See more for example
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28175631/how-to-measure-time-performance-of-a-compute-shader), [here](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Performance) and [here](http://www.lighthouse3d.com/tutorials/opengl-timer-query/)

Comment: Thanks! I'll take a look at all the 3 posts you sent.